# Versioning a code rewrite when the API does not change

Tags: semantic-versioning

I am the author of a plugin available on WordPress.org that is currently built upon the WordPress Plugin Boilerplate.

I've decided that my plugin does not warrant the extra bloat so I'm moving away from WPPB and completely rewriting it with a simplified class structure.

The plugin will have the exact same functionality, and this code rewrite will not to be noticable by the end user.

If my plugin is currently at version 1.1.2, what would be the next semantic version number for the above?

On one hand its a complete rewrite, on the other hand none of the features/API change.

(This is not WordPress specific, I'm just providing context to my question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your plugin currently has the version number `1.1.2`, then the next version number would be `1.1.3`. This follows the semantic versioning convention, which specifies that the third number in a version number (the "patch" number) should be incremented for minor changes or bug fixes that do not add new features or break existing functionality.

In your case, since you are rewriting the plugin with a simplified class structure but not changing its functionality, this would be considered a minor change and the patch number should be incremented.

However, if the changes you are making to the plugin are significant and add new features or change existing functionality, then you should consider incrementing the second number in the version number (the "minor" number) instead. This would result in a new version number of `1.2.0`.